# Using link_to to create image links

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to use the `link_to` method to dynamically create the image link. I have tried using `image_tag "/assets/#{student.name.downcase}.jpg"` as the argument for the link and I have also used `student_path` for the URL.

I can create this method to create text links but I am having problems in generating image links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
link_to image_tag("#{student.name.downcase}.jpg"), student
```

Answer (score 1):

Another variant to adding more complex markup within an anchor tag is to use a block.

```
<%= link_to student do %>
  <%= image_tag("#{student.name.downcase}.jpg") %>
<% end %>
```